# How to create table using oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Good evening I am a beginner in the Oracle database I wanted to create 3 tables as follows if you can explain to me please.

Architecture of my database:

[image: architecture of my database]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an Object Table:

```sql
CREATE TYPE country IS OBJECT (
  country_name VARCHAR2(100)
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE city UNDER country (
  city_name VARCHAR2(100)
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE capitol UNDER city (
  area VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE countries OF country;
CREATE TABLE cities OF city;
CREATE TABLE capitols OF capitol;
```

Then you can insert like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO capitols ( country_name, city_name, area )
VALUES ( 'Country', 'City', 'Area' );
```

and the `capitols` table has inherited the columns from its ancestor type.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=064ff1c64c4150b0283acf6fb54da374)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your ERD, you are looking to create three tables with foreign keys. Below is a script that will create them.

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
  country_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  name_country VARCHAR2(30)
);

CREATE TABLE cities (
  city_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  name_city VARCHAR2(30),
  country_id NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT country_fk FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
    REFERENCES countries (country_id)
);

CREATE TABLE capital_cities (
  capital_city_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  area VARCHAR2(30),
  city_id NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT city_fk FOREIGN KEY (city_id)
    REFERENCES cities (city_id)
);
```

A few explanations:

1. It's a good practice to name tables plural, and columns singular. This aids readability & creates syntactic cohesion.
2. Tables should have an independent primary key. This helps maintain data integrity, and makes creating foreign keys easier.
3. I made assumptions when defining your column datatypes. You can change them to suit your data. Most common Oracle datatypes are NUMBER, VARCHAR2, and DATE.
4. I made some assumptions about the relationships between your tables. I wouldn't call this good normalization, but you can learn more about database normalization by researching the topic (it is too broad to cover here).

Comment: thank you for your answer but I see no inheritance I specify that the database to use is oracle and not MySQL server

Comment: The syntax is Oracle based (I don't know if it even works with MySQL). There is no inheritance (from an object oriented definition) among database tables. Oracle databases are typically relational. Object relational mapping is a broad topic in computer science.

Comment: I explain to you what I wanted to do you see the `capital city` table it inherits from the `city` table so we must have ``extend`` in the same `city` table for the `contry` table it refers to the `city` table

Comment: @sabaykebremso: this SQL script does what you asked for. This is just how your data model should be represented in a relational database. You might want to have a look at the concept of [database normalization](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalisation).